# Android: how to inhibit radio button OnCheckedChangeListener listener

Tags: android, radio-button, listener

I have 3 `RadioButton`s inside a `RadioGroup`. There are 2 possibilities to refresh these `buttons`:

- from user interaction (OK)
- from refresh data (from my remote server) (OK)

When the user selects a `button`:

- My `OnCheckedChangeListener` is called, and a new value is send to the remote server (OK)

When a new refresh data arrives from the `server`:

- The coherent `RadioButton` is select (OK)
- But my `OnCheckedChangeListener` callback is called, and I don't want that.

How to inhibit in this case my listener ?

Thank you guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in your checked Change listener you done deselect the all three Radio button, If my guess is correct You will **set the flag** in callback you will **check the flag in checked Change listener** and **you won't do anything** if the flag is set. Or if the flag is Not set you perform your Logic..

Comment: Thanks Naveen ! I added a flag like your recommandation. It works fine now:-)